# Best way to propagate a data structure from a chain of project dependencies

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, microservices, grpc

I have a Controller project which calls a Provider project, and the Provider project calls 3rd party library:

```
Controller --> Provider --> 3rd Party
```

The controller want to get the information from a data structure (let's say `CustomInfo`) from the 3rd Party. The 3rd Party library provide a method to return an object of `CustomInfo`: `getCustomInfo()`

The `CustomInfo` has various data fields: enum, String, int, etc, for example:

```
public class CustomInfo {         
    private final String m_name;         
    private final int m_value;         
    private final String m_error;
    ...
    // getters and setters
}
```

There are 3 ways to do this I am aware of:

1. Import the 3rd Party library to the Controller project. Thus, the Controller project knows the `CustomInfo` data structure. But this way seems bad because of adding another coupling of the Controller with the 3rd Party library.
2. Copy and Paste the `CustomInfo`class definition from 3rd Party to Provider project. Then the Controller will only need to depend on the Provider project. But seems copy/paste class definition is a bad behavior too.
3. Call `getCustomInfo()` multiple times, each time returns a field value of the `CustomInfo` object. But this seems lots of redundant call of that `getCustomInfo()` method.

So which method is better? Or is there a 3rd method to solve this problem?

Comment: Can the Provider be configured with different 3rd Party libraries that perform similar tasks?

Comment: Currently there is only one 3rdParty library this Provider depend on. Dot you mean that I create anther library and providing it to both Provider and Controller? Thanks

Comment: No, I'm not asking you to create another library. I was just wondering if Provider was a wrapper around another service that can be implemented by multiple 3rd party libraries. For example, you see this for databases. Each vendor has their own library to connect but there are also libraries that allow you to connect to any database providing a common API.

Comment: For clarification, why does the controller want to get a data structure from 3rd party? This implies that #1 should be the solution. But as you say, that causes coupling that might not be necessary. We probably need more detail to help you here.